# Golang with Cassandra db using docker-compose : cannot connect (gocql)

Tags: go, docker-compose, cassandra, gocql

I am trying to setup a cassandra DB and connect to it with a golang app.

this is my `docker-compose`

```
version: "3.6"

services:
  cassandra:
    image: cassandra:4.0
    ports:
      - 9042:9042
    volumes:
      - ~/apps/cassandra:/var/lib/cassandra
    environment:
      - CASSANDRA_CLUSTER_NAME=mycluster

  myapp:
    ...
    ports:
      - 4242:4242
      - 4243:4243
    depends_on:
      - cassandra
      ...

networks:
  default:
    driver: bridge
```

I start the Cassandra using

`docker-compose up cassandra`

and then I wait it to be ready.

Then I try to connect to Cassandra in local using

```
> cqlsh
Connected to mycluster at 127.0.0.1:9042
```

and then I try to connect to it in my go app (dockerized) using `gocql`

```
    cluster := gocql.NewCluster("127.0.0.1")
    session, err := cluster.CreateSession()
```

( also tried to add element as `Consistency`, `ProtoVersion=4` etc. same results)

it says then :

```
Cannot connect to db: gocql: unable to create session: unable to discover protocol version: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:9042: connect: connection refused
```

Do you. have any idea why it can't connect?

thanks !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each container has its own localhost (`127.0.0.1`) address - you need to connect to IP address of your machine (if you use `bridge`), or maybe better to connect by the name (`cassandra`)

Comment: I'm not very fluent with docker-compose, how can I do that ?

Comment: In your app, you have to specify `cassandra` instead of `127.0.0.1`. As your app and Cassandra run in different containers, you can't use the localhost address, they are on the "different" hosts.

Comment: oh, yes i see it's working like that, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If both containers using bridge network you need to specify the network name in both containers and in your app container the host will be cassandra (docker) container.

```
services:
  cassandra:
    image: cassandra:4.0
    container_name: cassandra
    
    ports:
      - 9042:9042

    volumes:
      - ~/apps/cassandra:/var/lib/cassandra

    networks:
      - default
    environment:
      - CASSANDRA_CLUSTER_NAME=mycluster

  myapp:
    ...
    ports:
      - 4242:4242
      - 4243:4243
    depends_on:
      - cassandra
    networks:
      - default

    environment:
      - HOSTS=cassandra
      ...

networks:
  default:
    driver: bridge
```